# Reconstruct an IEEE754 floating point binary from a fixed point integer without FPO

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, fixed-point

I have a program which uses fixed point numbers, because the CPU I'm using doesn't support IEEE754 floats.

I've been doing fine with first converting standard IEEE754s into fixed points by finding the exponent, then shifting the number and so on by manually accessing the bits of the said IEE754 float inside the memory. After conversion, I'm able to do fixed-point calculations just fine.

However, is it possible to reconstruct a fixed point (say a Q15.16 integer) back to a IEE754 floating point without FPO so that CPUs with IEEE754/FPO support would be able to read it as their native float type? Is anywhere code or examples of how the CPU's FPO unit actually does this conversion in raw byte manipulation, or is it just some black magic that cannot be done in software? Obviously, I'm not looking for super-precise conversion.

All the answers I've seen until now use FPO. for example, by first calculating 2^(-num_fraction_bits_in_fixed), which already needs FPO, and then scaling the fixed point to that scaling factor.

Edit: By using EOF's answer as a baseline, I was able to create the following code snippet for reconstructing the IEEE754 float from a fixed point integer (In this example the fixed point is a Q31.32, stored inside a INT64). In the end, I just handled the case of 0 manually, since without it the code would actually return a really small, but still a non-zero value.

Here's the code:

```
static INT32 count_exponent(UINT64 x)
{
    INT32 l = -33;
    for (UINT64 i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        UINT64 test = 1ULL << i;
        if (x >= test)
            l++;
        else
            break;
    }
    return l;
}

UINT32 float_from_fix32(INT64 value)
{
    INT64 original_num = (INT64)value;
    UINT64 sign = 0;
    if (value < 0)
        sign = 1;

    // remove the signed bit if it's set
    INT64 unsigned_ver = value < 0 ? -value : value;

    // calculate mantissa
    int lz = nlz(unsigned_ver);
    UINT64 y = unsigned_ver << (lz + 1);

    // Our fixed-point is 64bits wide. 8 is the exponent bits for IEEE754
    UINT64 mantissa = y >> (33 + 8);

    // get the non-fractal bits, add the exponent bias ( 127 in IEEE754 )
    UINT64 non_fractal = (unsigned_ver >> 32);
    UINT64 exp = count_exponent(unsigned_ver) + 127;

    // construct the final IEEE754 float binary number
    // first add the last 23 bits (mantissa)
    UINT32 ret = mantissa;

    // add exponent
    ret |= (exp << 23);

    // special case of 0
    if(mantissa == 0 && non_fractal == 0)
        ret = 0;

    // add the sign if needed
    if (sign)
        ret |= 0x80000000;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I actually need to do the opposite of this! So this topic was super helpful

Comment: @proteneer I have ported the libfixmath to 64 bit machines. If you have 64bit machine without FPO, check out the library: https://github.com/jussihi/libfixmath64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, consider unsigned fixed-point number `x`, assuming (loss of generality here) that every number in your fixed-point format is (representable by) a normalized float of the floating-point format:

1) Find the number of leading zeros `n` (there may be special CPU instructions to do this quickly and without a (software) loop).

2) Shift the number left (`y = x << n+1`) (to produce a normalized float mantissa), then right (`m = y >> (signbit+exponentbits)`), this is the mantissa of the float.

3) Take your `n`, subtract the number of non-fractional bits of the fixed-point format, add the exponent bias of the floating-point format. Shift the biased exponent to the exponent bit-position of the fixed-point result.

4) If the original number was not unsigned, set the sign-bit in the result iff the number was negative.

---

a) If the fixed-point number is signed `v`, then convert to unsgined `u`, and keep the sign `s` separately (you can copy it to the sign bit of the floating-point number directly). The unsigned input to the above algorithm will be `x = v < 0 ? -u : u`.

b) `exponentbits` depends on the floating-point number format. For ieee754 32-bit `float`, it is `8`.

c) A fixed-point format typically represents number by an integer of `n` bits, which is (conceptually) divided by a constant of `2^m`. The non-fractional bits (if any exist) are the bits `n - m` if `n > m`.

d) `exponent bias` is again described by the floating-point format. For ieee754 32-bit `float`, the bias is `127`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you elaborate a little on these questions:
1. How many times do I shift if the fixed number is signed? n+1 or n? (If I first null the 0th bit which has the sign inside it)
2. What is `exponentbits`?
3. Are non-fractional bits here 15 or 16 if it is signed fixed point?
4. What is the exponent bias?

So in other words, your answer flew a bit over my head, could you elaborate a little. I'm not an expert when it comes to the IEEE754 standard

Comment: I've addressed some of your questions, but I'm not an expert on floating-point either. I have to ask, how do you do the float->fixed conversion without understanding floating-point numbers?

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now. Thanks, and sorry, the code I'm working on is part of an old project for which I combined some snippets and fixed the problems of those snippets by quickly looking at the IEEE754 spec back then. So more like, it's not in a fresh memory.. And clearly choosing something other than cryptic variable names in my float-->fixed conversion would've clearly helped here :) Thank you so much, marking this as solved.

Comment: Marking this as solved may be a bit premature, there may be off-by-one errors in the bias calculation in the answer as-is. Also, it requires the input to be equal to a normalized floating-point number, which is never true for a very exotic number (`0`), so you'll probably need to special-case that. I'd recommend writing a couple of good tests.

Comment: I've tested the above code attached to my original question enough for me to approve this answer now :)

Comment: @JussiHietanen Seems mostly ok. I will say though, my point about finding the absolute value of the input on unsigned `u` is not just for fun. If your code line `INT64 unsigned_ver = value < 0 ? -value : value;` is executed for `value == INT64_MIN`, the behavior is undefined, because signed integer overflow is undefined in C or C++. If the value is previously converted to `uint64_t`, the value will be bitwise-identical to the one you might expect, and the behavior is well-defined.